# Plugin MMQGIS thickness

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

I have a problem using the MMQGIS plugin. I try to export a layer to KML format using the plugin. I can run the process, however when I open it in Google Earth the line thickness is 5.0 which is a very thick size. Wouldn't it be possible to select the thickness before exporting? In the layer I try to export, the line thickness is not 5.0.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you export the Layer the normal way to KML?

Comment: I will try to explain better. I first import a dxf file that has an attribute table with a color column. then i apply line color based on color attribute. the lines are colored according to the color and when I use the mmqgis plugin it exports exactly with these colors but with a thickness of 5.0. when I export to kml normally the color symbology is not applied